# How To Use Complex Contour Integration To Obtain Zeros Of Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

Specifically, can someone recommend resources that continue from the end of this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKqC5uHjE4g&t=2s&ab_channel=zetamath?

Additionally, are there any alternative approaches, such as the Riemann-Siegel integral formula (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelIntegralFormula.html), that refine the use of complex contour integration for finding zeros? Explanations for these alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Till now I found:

- "Simple Zeros Of The Zeta Function" by N. A. Carella

Comment: I wrote a [blog](https://travorlzh.github.io/2021/01/19/zeta-zeros-count.html) years ago that derives a zero-counting formula for $\zeta$ in the critical strip.

Comment: thanks @TravorLZH. its helpful. Do you have any more? any other articles or keywords i should search for?

Comment: @TravorLZH do you happen to know about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730992/how-to-find-zeros-of-zeta-function-using-laurent-series-and-using-riemann-siegal approach? I am trying to find different ways of using contour integration to find zeros of riemann zeta function.